# Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null - Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have seen a couple of questions posted with this error on here and having seen some of the answers I noticed the general consensus is that it is caused due to the  DOM not being created yet. I have tried a few different solutions to fix it such as moving my script to immediately prior to the  tag, using log outputs before and after the image creation in order to ensure the object is actually being created correctly but nothing has resolved my issue. I am new to Javascript so it might be something obvious I am missing?

```js
var dice = [6, 6, 6, 6, 6];

function rollDice() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dice.length; ++i) {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    dice[i] = 1;
    document.write(dice[i] + "<br>");
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < dice.length; ++i) {
    var value = dice[i];
    var path;
    var ArrayImage = ["images/dice 1.png", "images/dice 2.png", "images/dice 3", "images/dice 4.png", "images/dice 5.png", "images/dice 6.png"];
    path = ArrayImage[value];
  }
  document.getElementById("dice_1").setAttribute("src", path)
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project 1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> This is a javascript application</h1>
  <script>
    console.log("script #1: %o", document.getElementById("dice_1")); // null
  </script>
  <div>
    <img id="dice_1" src="images/dice 1.png">
    <img id="dice_2" src="images/dice 1.png">
    <img id="dice_3" src="images/dice 1.png">
    <img id="dice_4" src="images/dice 1.png">
    <img id="dice_5" src="images/dice 1.png">
  </div>
  <input id="but" type="button" onclick="rollDice()" value="Roll Dice.">
  <script>
    console.log("script #1: %o", document.getElementById("dice_1")); // null
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/vupobaxovu/1/edit?html,console,output — I can't reproduce the problem. The first log logs null, but that is expected. The second one logs `[object HTMLImageElement] etc etc`

Comment: when I go into the console, i also get first output = null, second output saying it is there but then by roll dice function cannot find the id which is why im baffled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using document.write after the document has loaded, it's clearing the entire document (due to document.open() being called). Therefore, your img elements do not exist for setAttribute to be run against them. Try the following (note the index corrections that are needed due to array indexing starting at zero):

```
var dice = [6,6,6,6,6];
var results;
var resultsContainer = document.querySelector('.results');

function rollDice(){
    // clear results array
    results = [];
    for(var i =0; i<dice.length; ++i){
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*6 +1);
        dice[i] = num;
        results.push(dice[i]);
    }
    for(var i =0; i< dice.length; ++i){
        var value = dice[i];
        var path;
        var ArrayImage = ["images/dice 1.png", "images/dice 2.png", "images/dice 3.png", "images/dice 4.png", "images/dice 5.png", "images/dice 6.png"];
        path = ArrayImage[value - 1];
        document.getElementById("dice_"+ (i + 1)).setAttribute("src",path);
    }
    // convert results array to text with <br> between them
    var resultsStr = results.join("<br>");
    // display results as text to page
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = resultsStr;
}
```

Comment: removing that line has worked thanks, do you happen to know why it causes them to no longer exist if I keep the line in there?

Comment: From the MDN page on document.write: "Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document."

Comment: I've also fixed your rollDice function up a bit, to make it work the way I think you were intending.